# How to create hierarchy key options in Excel

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, ribbonx, excel-web-addins

I'm new to Excel add-in. I searched for hierarchy options but failed to find anything.

My questions are:

1. Can we create this type of **hierarchy** in the office js?

[image: Hierarchy Options]

2. Can we **disable** the items based on some condition?

[image: Disabled Items]

Can anyone guide on me this?

Answer (score 0):

All you can do with Office Add-ins is create labels and icons for particular controls on the ribbon and labels and icons for groups of controls. You cannot control how these groups and controls are displayed. Office decides how to do this based on factors such as the resolution of the screen, the size of the overall Excel window, and the number of icons in a given group.

However, you can use the [menu control](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/manifest/control-menu) to duplicate the behavior of pivot table button in your screen shot.

You can also make a control disabled the way the Design Mode and Refresh Data controls are disabled in your screen shot. This is done with a combination of manifest markup and an API. [Enable and Disable Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands)